# getsockname returns -1, errno is EBADF?

Tags: android, c, sockets, java-native-interface, sockaddr-in

The program runs up to the `getsockname` where the return is -1 and `errno` is 9 (`EBADF`， bad file descriptor). However, the code instrumented  in Android app goes well.

```
void sysLibCSendHookHandler(CPUState* env, int isStart){

if(isStart){
    int fd = env->regs[0];
    int buf = env->regs[1];
    int len = env->regs[2];
    int flags = env->regs[3];
    DECAF_printf("xxxxx send(%d, %p, %d, %d)\n", fd, buf, len, flags);
    extern int errno;
    struct sockaddr_un sock_addr;
    socklen_t sock_addr_len;
    sock_addr_len = sizeof(sock_addr);
    int t = getsockname(fd, (struct sockaddr*)&sock_addr, &sock_addr_len);
     DECAF_printf("fd:%d",fd);}
```

Comment: *"However, the code instrumented in android app goes well..."* - Does that mean the problem is in a simulator?

Comment: `EBADF` means the file descriptor passed to `getsockname()` is not valid. This code *implies* that you are somehow hooking the `send()` function, is that right? How exactly? This code is assuming the parameters are being passed in CPU registers, but they are usually passed on the stack instead. What makes you think the `send()` parameters are being stored in `env->regs[]` at all?

Answer (score 2):

This code results in undefined behavior:

```
extern int errno;
```

Per **7.5 Errors <errno.h>** of [the C Standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) (note the bolded part):

> The  header  defines  several  macros,  all  relating  to 
>   the  reporting  of  error conditions.
>
> The macros are
>
> ```
> EDOM
> EILSEQ
> ERANGE
> ```
>
> which expand to integer constant expressions with type `int`, distinct
>   positive values, and which are suitable for use in `#if` preprocessing
>   directives; and
>
> ```
> errno
> ```
>
> which  expands  to  a  modifiable  lvalue that  has  type `int` and 
>   thread  local  storage duration, the value of which is set to a
>   positive error number by several library functions.  **If  a  macro 
>   definition  is  suppressed  in  order  to  access  an  actual  object,
>   or  a  program defines an identifier with the name `errno`, the
>   behavior is undefined.**

According to the [Google Android source code](https://android.googlesource.com/kernel/lk/+/upstream-master/include/errno.h#28), `errno` is a macro defined as

```
extern int *__geterrno(void);

#define errno (*__geterrno())
```

That being the case, the value you see in your `extern int errno` is meaningless.